# Playing iPhone (iOS10) music in Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, rhythmbox, iphone, gvfs

I have been using Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 14.04 to play music from my iPhone for a while now. Sometimes I get the annoying "initialize your iPhone" dialog box, but I just cancel it, unmount and reconnect my phone, and the problem is solved.

### Background: Getting things to work with iOS 10

Recently, I updated to iOS 10, and mounting the iPhone stopped working. I somehow fixed this by cloning [libplist](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist), [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice), [libusbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd), [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd), and [ifuse](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse) [note: `ifuse` doesn't seem necessary if you use `gvfs`], checking out the `master` branch in each repo, and installing via

```
./autogen.sh
make
sudo checkinstall
```

so that the package versions and dependencies could be managed via `dpkg`.

For `libimobiledevice` I also did `./autogen.sh --disable-openssl` so that I'd use GnuTLS instead.

Because I had originally installed most of these packages via `apt-get`, I installed `libplist` as the dpkg package `libplist1`, `libimobiledevice` as `libimobiledevice4`, and `libusbmuxd` as `libusbmuxd2`. I also did `echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libimobiledevice-libs.conf` and some extra symlinking when programs complained that `/usr/lib/libimobiledevice.so.4` and such were missing.

### Getting gvfs to work

`ifuse` will now successfully mount the iPhone, but my actual goal is to get `gvfs` to detect and mount the phone so that it'll work with Rhythmbox. I may have needed to do additional symlinking to even get the `gvfs`-related programs to run, I forget.

If I naively try to plug in my phone at this point, I (with high probability) get the error message `Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)`. I have to run `/usr/lib/gvfs-gvfs-afc-volume-monitor` 3+ times until I get lucky enough for the phone to mount; this seems very wrong.

Running `sudo usbmuxd -f -v` spams me with messages like

```
New client on fd 19
Client 19 connection closed
Disconnecting client fd 19
```

over and over, plus an instance of `Receive from client fd 19 failed: Connection reset by peer` and `Connection reset by device 4 (3->62078)`. Basically, I have no idea why mounting only works intermittently. Things seem to work more often when I run `usbmuxd` in the foreground with `-f`, but that may just be confirmation bias.

When I finally *do* get the phone to mount, Rhythmbox will start and display the "initialize your iPhone" dialog, with two problems:  (1) it hangs for a long time while loading this dialog (trying to connect with phone, possibly, or maybe Rhythmbox is just ultra slow?) and (2) if I hit "cancel," I can no longer see the phone mounted on Rhythmbox. Before, after cancelling once, I could unmount and reconnect my phone and the dialog would no longer pop up, but this method is far less reliable because I can't reliably mount my phone! So after all this...

### Questions

1. Is there a "more correct" way that I should have gone about the installations from source?
2. How do I get `gvfs` to reliably mount my phone on the first try?
3. Should I stop using `gvfs`/`rhythmbox` and start using `ifuse`+something else?

Comment: Current workaround: unplug and re-plug phone 5-10x until I luck out. Please tell me there's a better way.

Comment: Workaround for the "initialize your iPhone" dialog: restart Rhythmbox instead of trying to plug the phone back in

Comment: update: "initialize iPhone" workaround doesn't consistently work because sometimes it'll just pop up the "initialize iPhone" dialog 100% of the time :(

Comment: Is your iPhone recoginzed by Rhythmbox at all? I'm using an iPhone SE with iOS 10.3.3 and try to accomplish the same thing running Ubuntu 16.04 and Rhythmbox 3.4. I can mount the devince using ifuse and see all the files and folders. But I have no luck with Rhythmbox seeing the phone.

Comment: I haven't tried in a while (esp. since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04), but in the past, Rhythmbox would see the iPhone, pop up the "initialize iPhone" dialog, I'd click "cancel", and then it wouldn't see the iPhone anymore.

Comment: Instead, what I started doing was just connecting my phone to my computer via Bluetooth and listening to music that way... but that has the problem that it forces me to use my phone to select songs to play or to see the song title, etc.

Comment: @jiangty - this would be really wild news, if Apple allows Linux as operating system to play music files - then we would not need to pay for music any more ... At Apple - Linux is indexed ...

Comment: Music downloaded from iTunes Store includes DRM controls - bypassing those is not something that is supported because that's technically violating your EULAs and potential other regulations or laws.

Comment: @ThomasWard This isn't for copying files, just for using my computer to control which songs play from my phone (and none of my songs are from the iTunes store anyway). Either way, I've basically given up on getting this to work well; I'd probably be better off mounting my songs on a network drive and streaming them.

Comment: I found this article regarding iphone - could be another option for you.  https://www.maketecheasier.com/sync-iphone-with-rhythmbox/

Answer (score -5):

You can play your iPhone's music by using your laptop/desktop speaker. To accomplish this, please follow the steps below:

1. Ensure your Ubuntu's laptop/desktop Bluetooth is turned on.
2. Turn on iPhone Bluetooth and pair with the Laptop/desktop.
3. Once pairing done connect your iPhone with Ubuntu via Bluetooth.
4. and play songs on iPhone and all your music buffer on your Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: **Khandu**, I've already [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1064991/revisions) your answer to improve readability, but all your points need screenshots or additional steps to ensure also someone not familiar with Ubuntu can follow your instructions... **@abu_bua** is referring to [this link](/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hi, I did mention this as a possibility in my comment here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/846845/playing-iphone-ios10-music-in-rhythmbox-on-ubuntu-14-04/1064991#comment1505090_846845. Unfortunately this means you have to select the music on your phone instead of on the computer.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: this obviously won't work.